# Cancel ActiveJob After Calling perform_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

After running `SomeJob.perform_later` I can see that job was enqueued in `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs`.

How can I remove the job from the queue if I already have saved `job_id`?

Basically I want to remove job from the queue.

Comment: @cschroed you should put that as the answer :D

Answer (score 3):

Calling `perform_later` will enqueue the job into whichever backend you use. The ActiveJob interface doesn't provide a way to remove jobs. If you are using Sidekiq as your backend [this documentation explains how to remove a job from a queue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#queue).